# (C++ Boost) Find item in list where member matches search term

Tags: c++, boost, find

Is there a nice way to simplify the following code into a one liner with C++ and potentially the boost libraries. I basically have a list of messages that have title() as a member function. I want to know whether a message with a given title exists in the list.

```cpp
std::string title = "some title";
bool unique = true;

BOOST_FOREACH(Message& m, messages) {
    if (m.title() == title) {
        unique = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you are familiar with C# Linq, a C++ version of the following would be great:

```csh
unique = (messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.title() == title) == null);
```

Unfortunately I can't use C++11, but if you have a C++11 example I would be interested to see it for future reference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least from the looks of things, you might want to use an `std::map` to store messages keyed by title:

```
std::map<std::string, Message> messages;
```

...in which case your search becomes something like:

```
bool unique = messages.find(title) == messages.end();
```

If you insist on doing a linear search and want to maintain your current situation with `title` being a member of `Message`, you could do something like:

```
bool unique = std::find(messages.begin(), messages.end(),
                        [title](Message const &m) { return m.title == title; }) 
                    == messages.end();
```

However, you *probably* don't want to do any of the above. Instead you probably just want to use `std::set` or `std::map`, but instead of searching to find whether the item is already there before adding it, just use insert, and it'll fail if an item with that key is already present (but be added if the title is new). Since we already looked at using `std::map`, let's consider how that would look with a set:

```
class Message {
    std::string title;
    // other stuff
public:
    bool operator<(Message const &other) const { return title < other.title; }
}:

std::set<Message> messages;

messages.insert(some_new_message);    // automatically unique
```

Depending on the situation (if you have a lot of messages, don't care about them being sorted) you might want to use `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::set` (and the same applies to `std::map` vs. `std::unordered_map`).

Comment: This is great thanks. Never considered using sets. I'll see if this fits in with the rest of my code.

My concern with using maps is I might have hundreds of these collections of messages, and each collection will be quite small. I was using a list to conserve memory due to the large number of collections.

Comment: @rpamely that sounds like a good trade-off to consider. However, favour std::vector over std::list for precisely the same reasons (locality). Linear search can outperform binary search for small collections, and certainly for tree based representations.

Comment: @rpamely: In addition to the data being stored, a list node has pointers to next and previous items, where a tree node has pointers to left and right subtrees, plus one bit of balancing information. Usually at least close to the same size.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I think in this case the best solution is to change it to a map.

But the other examples of how to search linearly will be helpful no doubt in other scenarios.

I'm interested though, for the std::find example does anyone know how to do this using boost lambdas? I've looked at the documentation and I'm not really getting it.

Comment: @rpamely: at least if you're always searching by title, instead of a boost lambda, I'd just define an `operator==` roughly like the `operator<` I showed above (but testing for equality, obvious).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ with boost, you should be able to do something like this:

```
bool unique = boost::find_if(messages, boost::bind( &Message::title, _1 ) == title) == messages.end();
```

Using [Linq](http://pfultz2.github.com/Linq/) in C++11 with boost, you should be able to write this:

```
bool unique = boost::empty(LINQ(from(m, message) where(m.title() == title)));
```

You can't use the same `first_or_default` in C++ since the default value is not a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I really like that boost solution.